# Record set-up in a page in PeopleSoft

Tags: peoplesoft

Wanted to ask if someone here knows how to set-up records as prompt table in pages through PeopleSoft.

So I have this EXT_ORG_ID (External Org ID Field) in my Level 0, and an ACCOUNT (Account Number) field in my level 1.
Now my ACCOUNT field has a prompt table named TP_ORG.

Inside TP_ORG are 6 fields:

EXT_ORG_ID

ACCOUNT

EFFDT

EFF_STATUS

DESCR

DESCR254

where EXT_ORG_ID, ACCOUNT and EFFDT are my keys. EXT_ORG_ID as the highest key.

Now it is my understanding that given that EXT_ORG_ID is a key to TP_ORG that it should show some results in my prompt table TP_ORG,

The problem is that it doesn't pull any. It doesn't even show the EXT_ORG_ID value in the level 0.

I dont know if this is enough information to give but can anyone help me about this?

Thanks